# Ejecutar un programa con Selenium en Windows, remotamente desde una app Android?

Tags: java, android, servlets, selenium, aws

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en **Android** , que envía peticiones a un programa, que tengo en una maquina virtual , con sistema operativo de **Windows**, este programa realiza una serie de acciones con **Selenium** en función de la petición que le llegue , es una **Java Web Application** con un **servlet** , funciona con **glassfish**, la cuestion es que me esta dando problemas a la hora de ejecutar **Selenium** en la **Java Web application**.

Alguien me puede sugerir una forma mejor para hacer esto , es que pienso que debe haber una forma mas sencilla y quizás me estoy complicando la vida, cualquier idea es bienvenida.

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción sería que ambas aplicaciones compartieran una base de datos común, en la que una (la app android) dejara las peticiones y la otra (el web) las recogiera, procesara y, si fuera necesario, dejara el resultado a disposición de la primera. Si fuera un sistema en tiempo real tipo Firebase que sincroniza las actualizaciones entre todos los clientes sería más ágil la petición/respuesta.

Otra opción es algún sistema de notificaciones push entre ambas.

Comment: Adolfo I. C. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, esa alternativa que me has propuesto me gusta , utilizar Firebase Realtime Database como intermediario entre las peticiones, también he visto que Firebase ofrece un apartado que se llama Functions , para ejecutar código Back-end sin necesidad de un servidor, le voy a dar una vueltecilla a esas dos opciones. Muchas gracias , un saludo.

Comment: No había visto la etiqueta aws en tu pregunta, pero ahora que lo pienso seguro que Amazon Web Services tiene alguna funcionalidad similar. De hecho, mi respuesta se basa en la experiencia con un proyecto sobre Azure en el que unas aplicaciones móviles dejaban "mensajes" (un tipo de almacenamiento que ofrecía por aquel entonces) y un worker role (un proceso continuo, lo que podrían ser las Functions de Firebase) en el servidor los iba procesando y desechando. Saludos y me alegra haber sido útil :)

Comment: Adolfo I. C. Gracias por añadir lo de AWS, lo he estado mirando y también puedes hacer un Back-End para aplicaciones Android, pero a diferencia de Firebase Fuctions que te obliga a hacer el Back-End en JavaScript, AWS te lo permite hacer en Java, asi que casi me viene mejor incluso, porque la lógica de el Back-End ya la tengo toda hecha en Java. Muchas gracias de nuevo, Un saludo! ;)